# In IDEA there is no connection to DB. Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password YES)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, intellij-idea

A couple days ago installed mySQL, wrote a program and it was working well. Restarted laptop today and can't get connection to DB. Nothing was changed.
Launched MySQL Workbench. The DB is visible:
[image]

The error in IDEA (I use free version Community):
[image]

If I press "Connect" by third mouse button:
[image]

How to fix it ? What the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a MySql grants issue, so not really a Java question. I wouldn't use root. Create another user and then as root you need to issue the correct sql statements. Google on 'msql create user' and 'mysql grant'

Comment: Thank's, but it did not helped. I've created the new user. Creared new Connection in Workbench for this user, checked in Workbench (SELECT USER(), CURRENT_USER();) that I'm under it, checked that I can manage DB from Workbench under this user, but still can't connect from IDEA. Not as root, neither new user.
fills like magic, like the problem is very tiny, but I can't get the logic what's wrong

Comment: Does it work without "DB Navigator" plugin?

Comment: I'm confused. We seem to have 'firstDb' and 'Javastudy'. Which is it?

Comment: Hello guys. firstDB - name of  the connection in IDEA, javastudy - DB name.
I've UNinstalled everything related to DB and installed it from scratch. Now it is working. I think there could be some conflicts between different programs-plugins, because before I understood how to install everything, I did all manually (plugins, connectors, setting etc.). Now all were done  automatically by Installer.
Thank you for the help! It was good to know how to create new user, gave some understanding

Comment: Please add an error text as well.

Comment: This is fixed. I had similar problems on 2 laptops. And as I've figured out the problem was in conflicts between elements of different DB servers. I've tried to install different DB servers before understood how to work with it. And this gone when I've cleaned absolutely everything related to DB and reinstall only one set but from scratch.